# Error: "Cannot Connect to Database Server"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am currently not able to access the local instance of MySQL from MySQL workbench home page. 
Primarilly, I was trying to install the LAMP stack on my Ubuntu PC following a video tutorial on LinkedIn learning named "Installing Apache, MySQL, and PHP".

Firstly, I installed apache using `sudo apt-get install apache2`.
 Secondly, I installed PHP using `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php-mysql`.
Then, I installed MySQL server using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
Added to this, I ran the mysql_secure_installation utility. When prompted some quetions, here are the answers I provided:

> Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD component: YES 
> Level of password validation policy: LOW 
> New password: PASSWORD 
> Re-enter password: PASSWORD 
> Remove anonymous users?: SKIP 
> Disallow root login remotely? SKIP 
> Remove test database and access to it? SKIP 
> Reload privileges tables now? SKIP 
> All done!

Next, I installed mysql-workbench using `sudo snap install mysql-workbench-community`

Once the installation was completed, I opened mysql-workbench and tried to access the local instance of MySQL through its reference on mysql-workbench home page.
I failed and got fired an **"Cannot Connect to Database Server"** error

Here is a full statement of the error:

**Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the MySQL server at localhost:3306:
An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.141" (uid=1000 pid=23118 comm="/snap/mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench-community (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.Secret.Service" member="OpenSession" error name"(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination =":1:14" (uid=1000 pid=933 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login " label="unconfined") 

Please:

1 Check that MySQL is running on address localhost

2 Check that MySQL is reachable on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)

3 Check the user root has rights to connect to localhost from your adresss (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)

4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from.**

I went through the suggested checklist as follows:

1. I ran `mysql> show global variables like 'port'` and found that I MySQL is running on port 3306 which is the localhost port.
2. I ran `netstat -tln` and found that a server is listening on port 3306 which is certainly MySQL.
3. I ran `mysql -u root -p  -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306` and after entering my password when prompted, I could access the MySQL server from terminal.
4. I am not even prompted to provide a password since I get the error immediately after clicking on the reference of the local instance.

I need help, please.

PS:

1. I could not install MySQL workbench using `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench` because I was getting the following error: **"E: Unable to locate the package mysql-workbench"**.
2. Once the mysql-workbench installation was completed, I got prompted : **mysql-workbench-community 8.0.22 from Tonin Bolzan (tonybolzan) installed**

Comment: SELinux , setenforce 0

Comment: I do not understand your comment mate

Comment: This seems to be your exact error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242026/cannot-connect-mysql-workbench-to-mysql-server

Comment: @EricShieh yes
It is exactly the problem I have and the solution suggested there works for me

Answer (score 0):

Only `sudo` can connect to the `root` MySQL account on most modern Ubuntu distributions. You will need to create an administrator account for yourself, which can then be used by MySQL Workbench and other systems.

Here's how:

0. With Ubuntu, open Terminal (or SSH into the machine if it's a server)
1. Connect to MySQL with the `root` account:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Create an account for yourself:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'russel'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```
3. Grant the account full access to everything:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'russel'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ```
4. Update MySQL Workbench to use your new account

This should get you going. Ideally, the `root` MySQL account will only ever be used when setting up replication or fixing something that has gone horribly wrong. Everything else should be done through an admin account.

Comment: I am getting fired the same error when trying to connect with the new user created with your suggestion